# How do I ignore words from a text file if I only want to read the numbers

Tags: c++

Here is the type of txt file I want to process to read only the numbers after each link:

```
http://example.com/object1   50   0
http://example.com/object2   25   1
http://example.another.com/repo/objects/1   250   0
ftp://ftpserver.abc.edu:8080   13   5
...
```

And here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    // input file
    ifstream infile;
    infile.open("ece150-proj1-input.txt");

    // output file
    ofstream outfile;
    outfile.open("ece150-proj1-output.txt");


    int input;
    int column = 0; // couting number of columns
    int row = 0; // couting number of rows
    int size = 0;
    int delay = 0;

    // calculation
    while (infile >> input) {       //------> Problem starts here
        switch ((column+3)%3) {
            case 1:
                size = size + input;
                row++;
                break;
            case 2:
                delay = delay + input;
            default:
                break;
        }
        column++;
    }

    infile.close();

    double averageSize = size/row;
    double expectedDelay = delay/row;
    double expectedTotalDelay = averageSize/1.25 + expectedDelay;

    outfile << "Average size = " << averageSize << endl;
    outfile << "Expected delay for priority = " << expectedDelay << endl;
    outfile << "Expected total delay = " << expectedTotalDelay << endl;

    outfile.close();
    return 0;
}
```

The outfile is always blank, I think it is because my int input will read the words, so it will stop reading the file. How can I deal with it ?

Comment: Assuming a word is everything that has whitespace (tab, space, newline) on either side, a number is just a special word. If you now define a function that define which of the words to ignore, you could easily solve your task. You will have to read the word as string though, not as number which already makes some assumptions about the nature of the word.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What if you replace the 'while' loop with the following?

```
while (!infile.eof()) {
    string url;
    int input1, input2;
    infile >> url >> input1 >> input2;
    size += input1;
    delay += input2;
    ++row;
}
```

Ofcourse, make sure you include 'string' header

Answer (score 0):

If you know that you will always have three columns per line of the input file, you can save 3 values at a time in your while condition.

```
sumDelay = 0;
sumSize = 0;
row = 0;
std::string address;
while (!infile.eof() && (infile >> address >> size >> delay) )
{
        sumSize =+ size;
        sumDelay =+ delay;
        row++;
 }
```